# ConsumingRouter to consume based on condition

Tags: java, functional-programming, stream

Started as to make a stream splitter to split stream based on condition, but finally found that I did ConsumingRouter, to consume based on condition and while have to provide consumers before using this router not as splited stream can provide consumers then , and use this router inside forEach of stream, please check it and provide me with your feedback and if there is another way to do it:

```
public class ConsumingRouter<T> implements Consumer<T> {
    private Map<Predicate<T>, Consumer<T>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void sub(Predicate<T> p, Consumer<T> c) {
        map.put(p, c);
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(T t) {
        map.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
            if (e.getKey().test(t))
                e.getValue().accept(t);
        });
    }
}
```

How to use it :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConsumingRouter<Integer> router = new ConsumingRouter<Integer>();
    Predicate<Integer> p1 = (i) -> i % 2 != 0;
    Predicate<Integer> p2 = (i) -> i % 2 == 0;
    Consumer<Integer> c1 = i -> {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Route 1 : "
                + i);
    };
    Consumer<Integer> c2 = i -> {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Route 2 : "
                + i);
    };
    router.sub(p1, c1);
    router.sub(p2, c2);
    IntStream.range(0, 1000).boxed().forEach(router);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a [`Map.forEach(BiConsumer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) that you can use as well:

```
@Override
public void accept(T t) {
    map.forEach((k,v) -> {
        if (k.test(t)) {
            v.accept(t);
        }
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you can convert that `if`-statement in the form of an [`Optional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) too ***if you can ignore `null` values (as commented by [@Misha](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105301/consumingrouter-to-consume-based-on-condition/105324?noredirect=1#comment193056_105324))***:

```
@Override
public void accept(T t) {
    // answer update: switched to Optional.of() for reasons mentioned in comments
    map.forEach((k,v) -> Optional.of(t).filter(k::test).ifPresent(v));
}
```

You can also take a look at this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940319/can-you-split-a-stream-into-two-streams) question for some insight about splitting two `Stream`s into two `Stream`s... similar to yours, except that you are only concerned with multiple `Consumer`s to *terminate* the source `Stream`.

**edit:** Oh yeah, you may want to consider having your `sub()` (subscribe?) method return the reference to itself, so that you can do method chaining as such:

```
router.sub(p1, c1).sub(p2, c2);
```

**edit 2:** [@Misha](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/105330/27975) has a **good** suggestion for doing away with the `Map`, if that suits your requirements as well.

Comment: You should use `Optional.of` rather than `Optional.ofNullable` in this case.  If you use `ofNullable`, it will handle `null` as if the `Predicate` returned false without actually calling the `Predicate`.

Comment: But `Optional.of()` throws `NullPointerException`... hmms, good point.

Comment: Right, since `Optional`-based logic will fail on a `null` value, throwing an `NPE` is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 5):

Making the `Consumer` maintain a mutable map is undesirable.  You can make `ConsumingRouter` an interface with no mutable state:

```
public interface ConsumingRouter<T> extends Consumer<T> {
    static<T> ConsumingRouter<T> of(Predicate<? super T> p, Consumer<? super T> c) {
        return t -> {if (p.test(t)) {c.accept(t); } };
    }

    default ConsumingRouter<T> andThen(Predicate<? super T> p, Consumer<? super T> c) {
        return this.andThen(ConsumingRouter.of(p, c))::accept;
    }
}
```

Then in your `main` you would use it like this:

```
router = ConsumingRouter.of(p1, c1).andThen(p2,c2);
```

Now you don't have to worry about somebody adding additional predicates while your stream is computing.

But is it really necessary to have a whole separate `class` or `interface` just for this?  You could create a simple static method:

```
public static<T> Consumer<T> acceptIf(Predicate<? super T> p, Consumer<? super T> c) {
    return t -> { if (p.test(t)) { c.accept(t); } };
}
```

And then use it like this (because `Consumer` already offers `andThen`):

```
router = acceptIf(p1, c1).andThen(acceptIf(p2, c2));
```

Comment: Nifty and short solution. :) A contrived reasoning for the `Map` is if OP has classes implementing `Predicate` and `Consumer` with `toString()` representations that can be displaying by calling `Map.toString()`... but yeah, I'll likely recommend this instead.